R: VGLM to Fit a Partial Proportional Odds model, unable to specify which variable to hold to proportional odds
Confirming my dependent variable is an ordered factor, gender is a factor of 0,1, main variable of interest (first listed) is my primary concern, and assumptions hold for only it when using Brent test.
When trying to fit using VGLM and specifying that it be treated as holding to prop odds, but not the others, I've had no joy.
> logit_model <- vglm(dep_var ~ primary_indep_var + 
+                       gender + 
+                       var_3 + var_4 + var_5,
+                     
+                     family = cumulative(parallel = c(TRUE ~ 1 + primary_indep_var), 
+                                         link = "cloglog"), 
+                     data = temp)

Error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component nor attribute") : 
  no terms component nor attribute

Any help would be appreciated!
With thanks
